# Hosting Laravel 5.7 project in Godaddy server

Tags: laravel

What will be my .htaccess code? I want to host my laravel project in godaddy server, my project path will be in public_html/coder.com ? In coder.com, i have to keep all my project files and folders. Any idea please someone help me.

Comment: Assuming you have godaddy shared hosting with cpanel. Usualy the .htaccess code shipped with laravel would work. If your project is an addon domain you can place your project directory in `public_html/your_website.com/` and point your domain to `public_html/your_website.com/public/`.

Comment: @ab.in Never put backend files in a publicly accessible directory. Bad idea.

Comment: what if directories have 755 and files have 644 permission?

Comment: @ab.in not if it's publicly accessible. Here's an interesting scenario. Do a google of this string => `db_username filetype:env` If the primary domain is pointing to `public_html` it is very likely that your credentials are exposed.

Comment: @ab.in you are right, i put my project in addon domain so what will be the index.php  file and htaccess.

Comment: @ Y.JoyCh.Singha use the default index.php and .htaccess file. Please note that I am not sure about the security concerns pointed by @user3532758. Please be sure you investigate on that before proceeding

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep backend files outside of the `public_html` folder. The content of the Laravel `public` folder should be placed inside `coder.com` folder. That is, you `index.php`, `.htaccess` and the rest should be placed inside `coder.com` folder.

Then, you need to edit `index.php` to point to the correct locations of `vendor` and `bootstrap` folder.

If, say for example, you placed the Laravel backend files in a folder named `laravel` at the same level as `public_html`, it should be `/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php` and `/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php`.

You do not need to edit the content of the default `.htaccess` file.

But, shared hosting almost always gives you unforeseen troubles. If you do not have shell access, you might need to ask for technical help from GoDaddy team to fix `symlink` issues if required.

Normally, there will be no issues with folder permissions, if there is you need to make sure that `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` is writable. `Never` ever give `777` permissions; `755` for folder/directories and `644` for files will be good. For this also, since it's shared hosting, you might want to seek technical assistance from GoDaddy.